# Find and Replace values in cells containing formulae for Excel 2016

Tags: excel, replace, excel-formula, find

I want to use the Find and Replace in Excel to remove all zeroes from a column that holds say the values of column A-column C. So A2-C2, A3-C3 etc. But because its a formula it just wont work even though I have tried the 'match case/Match Entire contents' as well as other combinations in Options.  This is a simple question but hard finding an answer as all questions seem to be directed at finding a part of a formula and replacing with something else.

Comment: Why are you trying to remove formulas that result in zeroes? What if the data changes; should you be replacing the formula(s)? Why not simply not display zeroes either through a custom number format or `ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False` ? [edit] How about an event driven macro like Worksheet_Change that removes the need for formulas altogether? What if the formula(s) simply returned a zero-length string (e.g. `""`) rather than zeroes?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to see a "0" or "#VALUE!" in these columns, I would rewrite the formula such that it excludes these values as outputs (meaning any sum or avg function would exclude these cells). Try using either "iferror" or "if" formulas to exclude see examples below.

- Excluding 0 using if statement: `=IF(H8*G8 = 0,"",H8*G8)`
- Excluding #Value! using iferror: `=IF(H8*G8 = 0,"",H8*G8)`
- Excluding 0 and #value using combined iferror/if statement: `=IFERROR(IF(G20*H20 = 0," ",G20*H20),"")`

If you want to exclude both 0s and #value! you can combine the formulas:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsaqU.gif)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not want to rewrite the whole range of formulas, you dan do it via VBA (hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>).Just paste that code somewhere in there. Now select the range you want to empty out of `0's` and `#Errors` and run the code:

```
Sub RemZeroErr()
  Dim rng As Range
  For Each rng In Intersect(Selection, Selection.Parent.UsedRange).Cells
    If IsError(rng) Then
      rng.Value = ""
    ElseIf rng.Value = 0 Then
      rng.Value = ""
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```